# How to remove \r\n and multiple back slashes from the database, and how to prevent it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table for my products descriptions with 2000+ products, The problem is when I enter a description for a product from my website there are two problems.
The database generates multiple back slashes next to every double-quote or semi-quote symbol.
And every time I edit the product the backslashes are doubled. Which looks like this after 3-4 edits for example:

> It'\\\s a very...

Then something like....

> It'\\\\\\s a very...

And so on...

I need something to mass remove them from my database as it will take days to remove them manually.

Also The second problem is

> \r\n

characters, which are generated next to every

> < br > or < br /> tag.

As you can probably imagine this is making my database very messy and spoiling the product descriptions. I have been trying to solve it many times, researching etc but I cannot understand it and how to stop it.

Can anyone help me to remove these and stop this from happening?

Would appreciate your help.
Regards

Comment: I also fetch this problem and I dont found any suitable solutions

Answer (score 2):

It is intresting, is it seems that you have the **NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES** mode on your MySQL.

I can reproduce the working in SQL Fiddle, if I use two different sql:

First:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  Name varchar(64)
);

SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';

INSERT INTO A (Name) VALUES('aaa \n\r bbbb')
```

Second:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  Name varchar(64)
);

SET sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';

INSERT INTO A (Name) VALUES('aaa \n\r bbbb')
```

I run a simple select like this for proof:

```
SELECT Name FROM A
```

Results:

**First case:** *aaa bbbb*

**Second case:** *aaa \n\r bbbb*

I hope it helped.

For furthe information pls check [MySQL sql modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes)!

End of course for the existing problems you can use a simple REPLACE function. But if you set the mode properly it won't happen again!

Comment: Hi, I don't know anything about NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES I have a simple textarea which posts to the database table products_description in a specific column. But the table holds more columns which never had this problem- this is a very strange part.

Comment: i saw some methods to replace those characters in the textarea before sending to database but I don't know which one exactly I can use and how to implement it.

Comment: Did you try run this method on your DB, like: SET sql_mode = 'ANSI'; ? There are some different sql mode, but you can try the ANSI for test. 
It is a property of server, so if you change it, the DB won't save \r \n or \'... So it is the long term solution, what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have used 'stripslashes' in the textarea which has solved the problem.